# How display a menu with different links on each page based on another menu/submenu joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla

I have in joomla 3.x the following "main menu":

**Departments**

-IT  (submenu)  
   -Quality Control (submenu)

**Research**
**Events**
....

When a user clicks on a department I need to have an additional menu displayed

*"Department menu"*. The menu will have the same link names but different URL links to different pages

More precisely

If I click on "IT"

the "Department menu" should show

"R&D Activities"

which will link to let say page A

if I click on "Quality Control" the "Department menu" should show 
the same "R&D Activities" but the link will be to another page page B

Any help is welcome!

Comment: This is a site administration question not a programming question. You will get a more detailed answer on [joomla.se]. What you want to do is in the module manager create separate copies of the menu module for each of your three uses (the top level and the two sublevels).  For the sublevel copies change the options so they only show the second level. Assign the copy modules only to the appropriate pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, less programming, and more administration, this question is.

Being said... assuming Research and Events are separate menus and not items in the same menu as Departments...

1. Go to Extensions -> Module manager and find the module for the Research menu (type will be "Menu") and edit it.
2. Go to the "Menu Assignment" tab.
3. For Module Assignment select "On on the pages selected".
4. Select the checkbox for the appropriate item under "Departments".
5. AND select all the items under "Research" [the menu you want to display], so that the menu remains active/visible when the current menu item is contained within it.

I use this same scenario on a Joomla web site I manage.  Visitors select a region (i.e. Northwest, Northeast, Central America) from a "Regions Menu". When a region is selected a special "Tours" menu appears.  I have a "Tours - NW", "Tours - NE", "Tours - Central America" in the back end.  Each have their own Menu module assigned to display on themselves or when the assigned item from the Regions menu selected.